# BigQuery Export Data Statement

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to test this statement out: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/other-statements#export_data_statement

Correct me if I'm wrong, but you can export query results to GCS?
Then why am I consistently getting the following error?

```sql
EXPORT DATA OPTIONS(
  uri='gs://my-test-bucket/*.json',
  format='JSON',
  overwrite=true
  ) AS
select status, count(1) as count
from `bigquery-public-data.austin_311.311_service_requests`
where created_date >= '2018-01-01'
and created_date < '2018-01-02'
group by 1
```

```
Cannot set write disposition in jobs with EXPORT statement
```

I've tried existing buckets, non-existing buckets, wildcards, no wildcards, changed the overwrite to False, used public and non-public datasets, nothing works. Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are in the Console UI - do below

Clink <kbd>More</kbd> then <kbd>Query Settings</kbd>

[image]

Then make sure you check Destination as below

[image]

... and don't forget to <kbd>Save</kbd> settings

Comment: Thanks @Mikhail - I checked the Query Settings and set the destination as suggested (although it looked like that option was already selected when I went there). It didn't work at first but I refreshed the browser and it worked. Thanks again!